# Limit of complex function help.

Tags: limits

What is this limit:

$$\lim_{z \to 2i}\, \left[\frac{(3z^2 + 2)}{(z-1)(z+2i)}\right]$$

when I plug in I get:

$$= \frac{-10}{(2i-1)(4i)} = \frac{-10}{-8 - 4i}$$

but the answer in my book appears to be:

$$= 1 - \frac{1}{2}i$$

Where did I go wrong? $3(2i)^2 = 3(4i^2) = 3(-4) = -12$ right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct, you just need to simplify it:

$$ \dfrac{-10}{-8-4i} = \dfrac{10}{8+4i} \cdot \dfrac{8-4i}{8-4i} = \dfrac{80-40i}{64+16} = 1-\frac{1}{2}i $$